# Is there a term for words that indicate "direction"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

For example, words like "left", "right", "close to", "above", "across from" etc.  I've found on a lot of websites they're called "directional words" but I was wondering if there was a more technical term.  I'm thinking of it as a subset of prepositions, words that only indicate some kind of relative position.

EDIT: I think one possible term is **spatial adposition**.

Comment: Most prepositions have some sort of spatial sense, but it's often metaphorized until all one can find is a figurative and often idiomatic sense. To be clear: there are no English prepositions that can **ony** indicate spatial position. There **are** a few English words that can only indicate time (_when, then, during, endure, duration_), but none for space. Space is [a metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf) most of the time.

Comment: And probably you ought to read the [Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html), especially the first two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps *[orientation](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/orientation_2)*

> the position of something in relation to its surroundings:
>   *The church has an east-west orientation (has one main side facing east and the opposite side facing west).*